# Is there any file manager able to restore the windows opened?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, file-manager

We know that `chrome` and `firefox` can remember the status of the tabs and can restore them next time.

Is there any file manager can do the same thing?

Comment: Good question.  Mac OS X "Finder" has an "Undo" command to undo file moves/renames/deletions, but no "restore windows" option except when recovering from a crash.  But your question is tagged gnome, so that's probably irrelevant for you.